# Set a 'www' on a WordPress subdomain OR how to tell Facebook that I've removed the 'www' subdomain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, wordpress

I recently moved my website to a WordPress multi site.

Introduction: because I'm using WordPress with multisite, it doesn't allow using the "www" as a sub-domain.

Problem: because of that I lost all the "likes".

How can I:

1. tell Facebook it's the same page so I won't lose the "likes"?

or

1. get WordPress with multisite to use the "www" subdomain

I've looked everywhere on the Internet, but I couldn't find any answer to the subject.

Yes, I know I can't move *likes* from one page to other, but what about just removing the `wwww`?
Or how do I get a WordPress multi-site to show a website with a subdomain of `www`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps you with your Facebook problem, but you should definitly redirect the www.whatever.com to whatever.com if you moved your site, so peoples bookmarks, and google now you moved.

The easiest way is propably to edit the .htaccess file in you root directory, to do the redirect. There are tones of online recources about that: Try adding above the wordpress stuff something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Not sure about Facebook though.